# what is (*this) in c language?

Tags: c

what is this pointer? 
it doesn't work in linux..but in visual studio it work
what happened??

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    typedef struct {  char name[20]; int id; } person ;

    // this function is my main problem        
    void print(person *this){
         printf("%s %d\n",this->.name,this->id);  
    }

    int main(){
        person p, q;  
        strcpy(p.name, "a");
        p.id=60151234;
        strcpy(q.name, "b");
        q.id=60155678;

        print(&p);
        print(&q);
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: That's just a parameter name.

Comment: Visual Studio does not come with a C compiler. It's not suitable for writing C programs.

Comment: @KerrekSB Visual Studio definitely comes with a C compiler. `cl.exe` can compile C programs. It's not entirely C99 conforming, but you can definitely use Visual Studio to compile C code.

Comment: @KerrekSB "it doesn't work in linux..but in visual studio it work". They probably used g++ to compile it on Linux, so it failed. I compiled the code fine with VS2013.

Comment: @PCLuddite: OK, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In C, `this` is a normal parameter name, no different from any other name.

You're probably using a C++ compiler, where `this` is a keyword and will give an error when used as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, `this` is a reserved word used in class methods as a pointer to the object in question.  It is *not* a reserved word in C, so in this case it's simply the name of the parameter.

This code will compile fine with gcc (provided you change `this->.name` to `this->name`), but it will not compile with g++ for this reason.

Comment: This isn't a question about C++.

Comment: @KerrekSB I understand that.  I mentioned it to provide a frame of reference to OP's issue.

Comment: I too understand that, but I just find it weird that the answer to a question about X starts with a long diatribe about Y. It's like an interview with a politician.